# Differences and best practices between integer, indexed column, foreign key, references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There are different possibilities in Rails to link models and tables together.

```
add_column :books, :user_id, :integer, index: true
add_reference :books, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

As far as I have read, I see that some Databases have different behaviors concerning this options.

I'm interested in finding what is the best practice to adopt for performances and for code readability.

I was using integer indexed column for a long time and I want to know if I should use reference with foreign_keys instead.

UPDATE: Exemple

In a brand new test app I've run:

```
 rails g model book author_id:integer:index user:references
```

The migration file looks like:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.integer :author_id
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :books, :author_id
  end
end
```

The ddl for the table

-- Table: public.books

```
-- DROP TABLE public.books;

CREATE TABLE public.books
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('books_id_seq'::regclass),
  author_id integer,
  user_id integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT books_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_rails_bc582ddd02 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.books
  OWNER TO my_user_name;

-- Index: public.index_books_on_author_id

-- DROP INDEX public.index_books_on_author_id;

CREATE INDEX index_books_on_author_id
  ON public.books
  USING btree
  (author_id);

-- Index: public.index_books_on_user_id

-- DROP INDEX public.index_books_on_user_id;

CREATE INDEX index_books_on_user_id
  ON public.books
  USING btree
  (user_id);
```

EDIT 2: Here is a link that describe the problem and points out the foreign_keys importance

[Link](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys)

Comment: Can you post the DDL generated for Postgres by the two options? I'm guessing one creates and actual foreign key constraint, and the other doesn't, but I am not that well versed in Rails.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. I'll post more info soon.

Comment: I added the DDL, there's a foreign key and two indexes as expected. Is there a big difference with and without the foreign key in terms of performances/stability ... ?

Comment: The difference is in data integrity, with foreign keys you have a pretty good guarantee that you'll never be referencing non-existent records. I know Rails likes to manage this on the app side, but that's never going to be as reliable as doing it in-database (I've never worked on a project where all data access was through one app, for example). There is, of course, a performance cost - those reference need to be checked when data is modified, but in most cases it's small, and I usually wouldn't consider dropping keys until I know there is an unacceptable cost. Correctness before performance.

Comment: Interesting point, so you would advice to always use the foreign key for the sake of data integrity? Would you consider making a answer with this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment a little: yes, the primary function of foreign keys is to maintain referential integrity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

As a side benefit, they provide a little more explicit information about your schema: query and design tools can make use of those relationships, rather than rely on shared column names.

It's also easy to check that all columns references by foreign keys are indexed, whereas otherwise you may only discover a missing index at query time.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

The performance implications are pretty easy to reason about: you're going to be doing an index lookup against the parent table whenever the data in a child table changes (insert/delete/update). For most small-medium tables you never have to worry about it.

Comment: So are `references` in Rails essentially `foreign_key` + `index` on that foreign key?